# Which design pattern should I use for storing collections?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have following task: Implement a mechanism that can take any collection of objects
(Array, List, etc.) and then allows you to read elements regardless of the container in
where they are stored. Please, tell me which design pattern should I use for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution probably will use the Iterator pattern, and could also use the Adapter (or wrapper) pattern.

I'm assuming that this is "homework", so I'm not going to provide you example code.

Comment: Thank you. May I use "Facade" pattern in order to hide getting of elements?

Comment: The Adapter pattern is probably mre appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The design pattern is called an [iterator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#Java), and Java lets you iterate over Arrays and Lists using a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Answer (score 0):

If all of the elements have the same type, then iterator is the way to go. If the different elements have different type, then sometimes visitor can simplify things over iterator.